# What is the difference between getter and a normal function in LWC js file

Tags: lightning-web-components

What is the difference between getter function and normal function written in LWC js file

Answer (score 3):

The getter function is automatically invoked whenever the value of any reference is changed. Whereas for normal functions, explicit calling is required.

For ex -
In the below example calling is not required for getter isValid. It will automatically invoked.

```
isChecked = false;
isLoading = false;

get isValid() {
    return this.isChecked && !this.isLoading;
}
```

Whereas in below example for normal function, you need call function

```
getMax(a, b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

handleClick(event) {
    // assume you want max value on some button click
    // you need to invoke the normal method as below
    this.getMax(a, b);
}
```

I have just taken random examples to explain. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

A getter is called whenever it is accessed to read a value, while a normal function is called through other means, such as an event handler or from another method.

As a simple example of a getter:

```
#counter = 0;
get counter() {
  return this.#counter = this.#counter + 1;
}
```

This will increment the count each time it is used:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(this.counter); // 1, 2, 3
}
```

In LWC, we typically use these to calculate dynamic values:

```
get helloWorld() {
  return labels.helloWorld[this.userLanguage];
}
```

However, be aware that if the value should change (e.g. because the user selected a new language), getters may not rerender correctly in all cases. This is because the framework only evaluates getters when a property bound to a template is modified.